# PHP Open file and write string in alphabetical order

Tags: php

I have a file that I'm trying to write a string to, and want to do so based in alphabetical order but am unsure how to do it.

I can open the file, which has a huge list (example below) of how the files are arranged, first in alphabetical order by their sections and then by their filenames.

What I would like and am trying to do in my php script is open the file, search alphabetically based on the second word `/section/` then by the third `/filename=1` and insert the string in the proper order.

I already know how to open the file and append the string at the bottom but have **no** clue how to search alphabetically and if its even possible (though of course it is, at least I think). I'm reading through tons of answers and php manuals and perhaps I'm too tired but I'm missing it.

```
rooms/creative/thelastofus=1
rooms/creative/thetombs=1
rooms/creative/varekai=1
rooms/erotic/denofdecadence=1
rooms/erotic/dungeon=1
rooms/fantasy/americangods=1
rooms/fantasy/arvandor=1
rooms/gorean/aldushara=1
rooms/gorean/grpexplorations=1
rooms/history/blackethornebluff=1
rooms/history/sandsoftime=1
rooms/supernatural/ahsgenocide=1
rooms/supernatural/ahspurgatory=0
rooms/reality/grafica=1
```

So basically I need it to open the file, search alphabetically. Then insert the string `rooms/section/filename=1` in the right order.

I would be eternally grateful for any pointers in the right direction.

Comment: Couldn't you just loop through them and place them into an array then organize them that way? I'm not sure just thought of it as I was reading this. Definitely is not efficient but I believe it should work. Also a sample code that you've created would be great for us that are trying to help.

Comment: You may be correct on that I'm just having a hard time figuring out where to start and how to place every line into an array to loop through them I'm working on sample code now as I go trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put each line in an array and then just sort them like this:

```
$testArray = sort($testArray);
```

It will sort it in alphabetical order. Then you can do whatever you want to it. Loop it into a string to output. Or compare for instance.

See this if you could use some more info on the subject:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_sort.asp

Comment: that's a huge array, but if I'm understanding it'd be something like $test=array("rooms/reality/bigslice=1","rooms/reality/grafica=1","rooms/gorean/aldushara=1","etc","etc","etc");
sort($test);  Is that about right to get them to sort?

Comment: Yep :) that's it exactly. You can always figure out a way to split the content to add them dynamic. (think substr, or something with a splitter)

Comment: beautiful, thank you for that. now I just need to figure out how to write it in the proper location once it finds where it should be unless I'm overthinking it.

Comment: Besides, array's being huge is exactly what they are used for. They are basicly here to organize big amounts of data. 

If the answer helped would you be so kind to accept it as answered? :)

Comment: I will certainly and that makes sense, though I am curious how it will work as the list will keep growing exponentially as new lines are added how to ensure it finds those in the array later, if that makes sense.

Comment: check out this function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php If you make a new question here on stack overflow and tag me in it I can explain it to you more elaborately.

Comment: `$testArray` is equal to 1. `sort()` works in place. It mutates the array and does not return a new array.

Comment: Thank you both, will be fiddling with this and see if I can get it work and will tag you on a new question if can't get it to go through.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you would use a user-defined sort to sort the files by folder and filename. In my testing comparing strings with "<" worked as expected.

```
$arr = ['rooms/creative/thelastofus=1'
,'rooms/fantasy/americangods=1'
,'rooms/fantasy/arvandor=1'
,'rooms/creative/thetombs=1'
,'rooms/creative/varekai=1'
,'rooms/erotic/denofdecadence=1'
,'rooms/erotic/dungeon=1'
,'rooms/gorean/aldushara=1'
,'rooms/gorean/grpexplorations=1'
];

print_r($arr);

uasort($arr, function($a,$b){
  $splitA = explode('/',$a);
  $splitB = explode('/',$b);
  if( $splitA[1] == $splitB[1] ){
    //Compare filenames
    if( $splitA[2] == $splitB[2] ){
      return 0;
    }
    else{
     return $splitA[2] < $splitB[2] ? -1 : 1; 
    }
  }
  else{
   return $splitA[1] < $splitB[1] ? -1 : 1;
   }
});

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: thank you as well thats the basics of what I needed to get started in figuring it out.